# DB::raw inside DB::raw. I cant use concat inside find_in_set in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my laravel code

```
$productDetails = DB::table('products')
        ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategories_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
        ->join('size_categories', 'subcategories.categories_id', '=', 'size_categories.categories_id')
        ->join('sizes',function($join){
            $join->on(DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET("+ DB::raw("CONCAT('\'',sizes.id,'\'') AS ID") +", size_categories.size_id)"),">",DB::raw("'0'"));
         })
        ->where('products.id', $request->id)
        ->select('products.name','products.image','products.id',
            'products.image_second','products.description','products.min_order','size_categories.size_id')
        ->get();
```

The query i want is

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(sizes.name),`products`.`name`, `products`.`image`, `products`.`id`, `products`.`image_second`, `products`.`description`, `products`.`min_order`, `size_categories`.`size_id` from `products` 
inner join `subcategories` on `products`.`subcategories_id` = `subcategories`.`id` 
inner join `size_categories` on `subcategories`.`categories_id` = `size_categories`.`categories_id` 
join sizes on (FIND_IN_SET(concat('\'',sizes.id,'\''),size_categories.size_id)>0) where `products`.`id` = '7'
```

How do i do that, please help.
I even tried removing the inner DB::raw, but nothing works.
I dont have any query when checking on telescope.
I am new to laravel.

Group_concat is also not working now

```
->select(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(sizes.name)'),'products.name','products.image','products.id',
            'products.image_second','products.description','products.min_order','size_categories.size_id')
```

I think the code is right, but where is the problem

Comment: what is your query now? try dd($query->toSql())

Comment: Just as a reminder, in PHP `+` is strictly a mathematical operator. Dot (`.`) is for string concatenation

Comment: it is an ajax request, when i use dd, i dont get anything

Comment: Why do you have nested `DB::raw` you shouldn't need to do that?

Comment: Sir changed my code to `("FIND_IN_SET(". DB::raw("CONCAT('\'',sizes.id,'\'') AS ID") .", size_categories.size_id)")` still it doesnt works

Comment: @ShahRukh try with Log the query. Let us know what is your actual query. Otherwise its really hard to help you

Comment: yeah its working now, damm. Thank you. But i tried it before , it wasnt. anyways it is now.

Comment: @GiacomoM Sir it works now, i removed in nested one, How do i log the query? when i use ajax request, because dd doesnt show anything

Comment: Note that `on(DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(CONCAT('\'',sizes.id,'\''), size_categories.size_id)"), >, 0)` should be functionally equivalent to what you had (also more readable). I'm also not convinced you need to concatenate the quotes in the size.id either

Comment: yeah you are right. i thought, find_in_set will find 1 if there is data like 12,31,4 in my table. but its working fine without quotes. thats why i used quotes to differentiate them. Thank you for this

Comment: Sir please have a look at my edited question, group_concat isnt working. i find for solution everywhere, it should work

Comment: @ShahRukh add use Log; at the start of the file and after that you can use the code Log::info('your log string');

Comment: Thank You Sir, much appreciated